# Is it possible to track display driver memory accesses over PCIe?

Tags: linux, graphics, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, pci-e

Our team wishes to write a performance measuring tool with focus on GPUGPU
In order to understand if a particular app is compute-bound or memory-bound we would like to track Graphic card's memory accesses without sticking to any compute API
Is it possible to track syscalls like read for this purpose?

Comment: `strace` would show you syscalls, but it's unclear that the actual memory access would originate in userspace and not in some kernel driver.

Comment: @Chris, it sounds like the memory accesses they want to trace aren't originating from the CPU at all, but from the graphics card.

Comment: That would make syscalls rather irrelevant... at least as the direct actor, though perhaps it's possible to identify triggering interactions.  My suspicious is that the asker needs to do a lot more studying of the architecture before any practical experiments.

Comment: It’s possible to trace all MMIO accesses (x86 only for now) for the given device driver.

Comment: @0andriy how MMIO can be traced?

Comment: Surprise, surprise — with *mmiotrace*. It actually had been developed to trace GPU  MMIO accesses. https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/Documentation/trace/mmiotrace.rst